# How to rotate a Vector2?

Tags: c#, .net, xna

I'm trying to rotate a Vector2 but nothing work.
I've tried the following -> didn't work:

```
x' = cos(angle)*x - sin(angle)*y & y' = sin(angle)*x + cos(angle)*y
```

I've tried using a rotation matrix -> didn't work

What am I doing wrong ? :/

```
angle = MathHelper.Pi;
direction.X = (int)((direction.X) * Math.Cos(angle) - direction.Y * Math.Sin(angle));
direction.Y = (int)((direction.X) * Math.Sin(angle) + direction.Y * Math.Cos(angle));

float angle = MathHelper.PiOver2;
Vector2 dir = new Vector2(direction.X, direction.Y);
Vector2.Transform(dir, Matrix.CreateRotationX(angle));
direction = new Point((int)dir.X, (int)dir.Y);
```

Answer (score 12):

[Vector2.Transform()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb199533.aspx) returns a result rather than applying the changes in-place.

```
var transformed = Vector2.Transform(dir, Matrix.CreateRotationX(angle));
direction = new Point((int) dir.X, (int) dir.Y);
```

Comment: Do not be too harsh on yourself. This is one class of mistake you will find yourself repeating once a year (with identical confusion each time) for the rest of your programming days.

Comment: I think it should be `CreateRotationZ`, since you want to rotate about the Z axis.

Answer (score 1):

The first method you have written should work, as it's showed here also: http://www.oocities.org/davidvwilliamson/rotpoint.jpg

Remember to store the original values, and use those to determine the new values, and do not use the new x value to calculate y. Or store the products in separate variables.

Comment: I did (the pasted code is an old version) but it did'nt work anyway :/

Comment: +1 for the "Remember to store the original values, and use those to determine the new values". I spent like 30 minutes trying to debug my code. I feel dumb now